# Create URL based on user input

Tags: java, html

I am very new to Java and will like to learn it by applying in my work.

I will like to generate a link based on user input via drop down list.

`https://example.com/"input1"/testing_"input2"_xx.html`

> Input 1 drop down list
>
> Input 2 is date

How do I concatenate input 1 and 2 into the URL?

Comment: Your question says *Java* but your tags say *JavaScript*. That's like being unsure if you mean Car or Carpet. Which language are you actually using?

Comment: Please hit the *edit* link and read the formatting instructions next to the question. Indent code to make it readable. Use the formatting buttons in the editor to help.

Comment: Also your URL is not valid. There is a trailing bracket

Comment: Thank you all for the comment, edited as per suggested.

Comment: I'd suggest adding information about how you are connecting html to Java as well (reading a file, web app, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get the values of the input fields:

```js
function generateURL()
{
var part1 = document.getElementById('part1').value;
var part2 = document.getElementById('part2').value;
var url = "https://example.com/"+part1+"/"+part2+".html";
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = url;
}
```

```html
Part 1 of URL:<br/>
<select id="part1">
<option value="one">one</option>
<option value="two">two</option>
<option value="three">three</option>
<option value="four">four</option>
</select>
<br/>
Part 2 of URL:<br/>
<select id="part2">
<option value="one">one</option>
<option value="two">two</option>
<option value="three">three</option>
<option value="four">four</option>
</select>
<br/>
<button onClick="generateURL();">Generate URL</button>
<br/>
URL Generated:
<span id="result"></span>
```

In place of the second dropdown select you can use anything from date to input box.

**UPDATE**
 A date example:

```js
function generateURLX()
{
var partx = document.getElementById('partx').value;
var party = document.getElementById('party').value;
var urlx = "https://example.com/"+partx+"/"+party+".html";
document.getElementById('resultx').innerHTML = urlx;
}
```

```html
Part 1 of URL:<br/>
<select id="partx">
<option value="one">one</option>
<option value="two">two</option>
<option value="three">three</option>
<option value="four">four</option>
</select>
<br/>
Part 2 of URL:<br/>
<input type="date" id="party" placeholde="Date">
<br/>
<button onClick="generateURLX();">Generate URL</button>
<br/>
URL Generated:
<span id="resultx"></span>
```

Comment: THANK YOU so much Shakti!!! I will like to know how do i convert the date to text so it can appear in YYYYMMDD instead of date format YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: use this `var res = str.split("-").join("");`

Comment: `str` is your date variable.

Comment: Thank you all for the advise so far everyone. To perfect this coding, how do I make the final result a clickable hyperlink instead of just text?

Comment: Come on. Do some work yourself. `document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '<a href="'+url+'">Click</a>`

Comment: Hi @mplugjan, ty for your advise, although your code did not worked but manage to play around with it and get it working! Basically I create a variable with href tab and link it to document.getElemetById('resultx') .innerHTML.

Comment: Hi @praveena, can I ask if there a code that I can remove the day from the date acquired from user input. example I only want YYYYMM. Thank you in advance for the replied!

Comment: `var fullDate = new Date("2017-12-12"); 

var twoDigitMonth = ((fullDate.getMonth().length+1) === 1)? (fullDate.getMonth()+1) : '0' + (fullDate.getMonth()+1);
 
var currentDate = fullDate.getDate() + twoDigitMonth ;` this is change your date format

Comment: @praveena, ty for the advise again. Is there a code to actually remove the DD from var party from my code then applied the split & join advise by you earlier to give me the end result of YYYYMM.

Comment: `var fullDate = new Date(party);
 
var twoDigitMonth = ((fullDate.getMonth().length+1) === 1)? (fullDate.getMonth()+1) :  + (fullDate.getMonth()+1);
 
 if(twoDigitMonth<10)
 {
 twoDigitMonth="0"+twoDigitMonth;
 }
 
var currentDate = fullDate.getFullYear() +""+  twoDigitMonth;` try this

Comment: @praveena, thank you a million, after reading through your code and do the necessary editing, it worked! Thank you very much as I learn a lot from this post.

Comment: Missed a quote - the code works: `document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '<a href="'+url+'">Click</a>'`